# How to search a column in multiple tables in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, search, select

There are several tables with many columns and it takes forever to manually find the column I need. How do I search for my column from whatever table it exists in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%columnName%'
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't know my Table Name. I'm also searching which table the column exist in.

Comment: This will return column_name and table_name for every column that has columnName in it's name in the database you are working on.

Comment: It makes sense now. Thanks! :D

Comment: I'm about to do so, it's asking me to wait!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [sys.columns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) view and then join to the [sys.tables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) view to get that information.